# Finding out where in Magento the trailing slash is being removed

Tags: url-rewrite

Bit of a bizarre and unhelpful question but I am unsure how to get to the bottom of this one currently...

All the trailing slashes are being removed and 301 redirected to the URLs without a trailing slash and I cannot figure out where this is occurring.

- There isn't anything in `.htaccess` handling this.
- There isn't a URL suffix handling this for products or categories.
- There is no local code pool Mage override handling this.
- As far as I can make out, there are no third party extensions handling this.

The worrying thing is, I think I myself set this up...

Any other ideas?

### Edit

Actually, I just replaced the `.htaccess` with the default one from Magento and the URLs with the trailing slash did not 301 redirect to those without so it actually seems like it is something missing in the .htaccess that is actually needed in order for these to resolve... This should be interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this is quite incredible.

This had nothing to do with anything in `mod_rewrite` at all.

Or anything that we had even customised in `.htaccess`.

cPanel, or the hosting company for this particular store were auto-inserting stuff in the file, specifically, the below:-

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the â€œea-php56â€ package as the default â€œPHPâ€ programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Removing this no longer caused URLs with a trailing slash to 301 redirect to those without. Can't say I see how but then, I am not overly familiar with `mime_module`. Either way, this is plain ridiculous and needless to say, we do not handle the hosting for this website!

### Edit

Oh brilliant! Found out that PHP on the server had been updated to version 7 and no-one had even informed us or even consulted us on this (thus likely triggering the auto-insertion of `mime_type` into `.htaccess`). Sigh.

Anyway, hope this helps someone out there one day!

Comment: If it's solved, please mark your answer as accepted. :)